# How to programmatically dim back-lit input buttons?

Tags: java, android

I am writing an app to dim the screen, how can I dim the back-lit input buttons on the bottom of the screen from a service?

Launching an invisible non-touchable non-focusable activity is not an option as it blocks launching of other activities.

Suggestions?

Comment: It's probably impossible. Hardware lights are usually managed internally by the device and not exposed through any API

Comment: While there are ways for the foreground activity to affect the behavior of the system bar/navigation bar/whatever-they-call-it-today bar, I doubt that it is possible for a service to change it.

Comment: I have observed other apps doing this, so I know it's possible. The question is now how. If anyone has any idea, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
```

you will need

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
```

in your library manifest.

Also set target SDK to 11 in your properties for the library and shells if applicable

Comment: Currently using code > mTopView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);//<  However, it is not working.

Comment: Support for this has not been consistent across different versions. beyond ensuring that your target is correct and is set everywhere where it needs to be, I can't really help. Also what phone are you developing on? It worked for me on my nexus s